# How to access shared folder between CentOS 6 and WinXP under vmware player 4

Tags: centos, vmware-player

Based on [Sharing Files between CentOS 6 and Windows Systems with Samba](http://sureshdangi.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/sharing-files-between-centos-6-and-windows-systems-with-samba/)

I am able to follow until section of "**Accessing Samba Shares**". however, my system is WinXP and I don't see CentOS 6 icon at all. In my left panel of explorer, I only see "My network places".

For section "**Accessing Windows Shares from CentOS 6**", after I click workgroup, I only see a localhost icon. When I click this icon, I see "unable to mount location" error from CentOS.

BTW: I have set the shared folder within WMWare Player 6.0.

Whatelse I have to do in order to make the shared folder work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Shared folder with in WMware Player 6.0

Virtual PC on when you turn on the status of the LAN on the PC physically will automatically connect as well.

if you just want to share a folder without the need Virtual PC to connect to the internet, simply setting ip with the same class, for example:
    in your physical PC IP 192.168.1.2 Addressnya
    then in your virtual LAN IP 192.168.1.3 Addressnya
    then, sharing your folder.

but if you want your Virtual PC is also connected to the internet then you have internet sharing on your physical network card.
Open Network Connections and right click on your physical network card and select Properties.

select advanced and checklist in Allow users to connect other

if there appears underneath option, select the name of the virtual network card, if not immediately oke wrote.
  If you use internet connection sharing is the virtual IP network card you will automatically be 192.168.0.1

The next setting on the virtual IP on your network with

IP 192.168.0.5

Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1

Primary DNS: 192.168.0.1

Preffered DNS: 202.134.0.155

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following step to fix the problems:

1. From VMWare Player, choose Virtual Machine/Install VMWare Tools
2. Create a temporary folder:

   ```
   mkdir -p /tmp/vmwaretools
   ```
3. un-tar the file to the temporary folder:

   ```
   tar -C /tmp/vmwaretools -vxzf /media/VMware\ Tools/VMwareTools-8.8.4-743747.tar.gz
   ```
4. Enter the folder where the installer is located:

   ```
   cd /tmp/vmwaretools/vmware-tools-distrib/
   ```
5. Become [superuser](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/su.1.html):

   ```
   su -
   ```
6. Run the installer:

   ```
   ./vmware-install.pl and accept all defaults
   ```